# dwm.exe causing BSOD "DRIVER_OVERRAN_STACK_BUFFER" in W10

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I have a high frequency of BSODs in my computer pointing to many different reasons. A recent case is this dwm.exe causing "DRIVER_OVERRAN_STACK_BUFFER" BSOD. How can I fix it? Btw I'm under the impression I'm getting this BSOD while playing CS GO. My computer:

- AMD Ryzen 7 1800x + NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB MSI, 8GB RAM Corsair LPX Vengeance (1 part missing)

As someone who experiences dozens of BSOD per month, I've already checked memory, updated drivers, reinstalled Windows (keeping the drivers), did those scanf chkdsk etc.. Here is memory.dmp analyze results:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 AMD64 Copyright
>   (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP] Kernel Bitmap Dump File:
>   Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be
>   available.
>
> Symbol search path is: srv* Executable search path is:  Windows 10
>   Kernel Version 18362 MP (16 procs) Free x64 Product: WinNt, suite:
>   TerminalServer SingleUserTS Built by:
>   18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202 Machine Name: Kernel base = 0xfffff803`1ae00000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff803`1b248150 Debug
>   session time: Fri Apr  3 19:02:33.498 2020 (UTC - 3:00) System Uptime:
>   1 days 1:41:00.176 Loading Kernel Symbols
>   ...............................................................
>   ................................................................
>   ................................................................ ..
>   Loading User Symbols PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 00000088`f09c8018). 
>   Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details Loading unloaded module list
>   .......... For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v 4: kd> !analyze
>   -v
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> DRIVER_OVERRAN_STACK_BUFFER (f7) A driver has overrun a stack-based
>   buffer.  This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain
>   control of this machine. DESCRIPTION A driver overran a stack-based
>   buffer (or local variable) in a way that would have overwritten the
>   function's return address and jumped back to an arbitrary address when
>   the function returned.  This is the classic "buffer overrun" hacking
>   attack and the system has been brought down to prevent a malicious
>   user from gaining complete control of it. Do a kb to get a stack
>   backtrace -- the last routine on the stack before the buffer overrun
>   handlers and bugcheck call is the one that overran its local
>   variable(s). Arguments: Arg1: ffffe70ae08b5888, Actual security check
>   cookie from the stack Arg2: 0000fc951f5cc688, Expected security check
>   cookie Arg3: ffff036ae0a33977, Complement of the expected security
>   check cookie Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero
>
> ### Debugging Details:
>
> KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1
>
> PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1
>
> SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1
>
> STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1
>
> TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1
>
> DUMP_CLASS: 1
>
> DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401
>
> BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
>
> SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer
>
> SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name
>
> SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU
>
> SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version
>
> BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.
>
> BIOS_VERSION:  5220
>
> BIOS_DATE:  09/12/2019
>
> BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
>
> BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  PRIME X370-PRO
>
> BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev X.0x
>
> DUMP_TYPE:  1
>
> BUGCHECK_P1: ffffe70ae08b5888
>
> BUGCHECK_P2: fc951f5cc688
>
> BUGCHECK_P3: ffff036ae0a33977
>
> BUGCHECK_P4: 0
>
> SECURITY_COOKIE:  Expected 0000fc951f5cc688 found ffffe70ae08b5888
>
> CPU_COUNT: 10
>
> CPU_MHZ: e09
>
> CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD
>
> CPU_FAMILY: 17
>
> CPU_MODEL: 1
>
> CPU_STEPPING: 1
>
> BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)
>
> BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)
>
> BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)
>
> BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  0xF7
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  dwm.exe
>
> CURRENT_IRQL:  0
>
> ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  doesn't matter ;)
>
> ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  04-03-2020 19:08:42.0261
>
> ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 amd64fre
>
> LOCK_ADDRESS:  fffff8031b262940 -- (!locks fffff8031b262940)
>
> Resource @ nt!PiEngineLock (0xfffff8031b262940)    Available
>       Contention Count = 50 1 total locks
>
> PNP_TRIAGE_DATA:      Lock address  : 0xfffff8031b262940  Thread Count  :
>   0     Thread address: 0x0000000000000000  Thread wait   : 0x0
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8031b07c8a5 to fffff8031afc2380
>
> STACK_TEXT:   ffffe70a`e08b4638 fffff803`1b07c8a5 : 00000000`000000f7
>   ffffe70a`e08b5888 0000fc95`1f5cc688 ffff036a`e0a33977 :
>   nt!KeBugCheckEx ffffe70a`e08b4640 fffff803`1afa2c82 :
>   ffffe70a`e08b4780 0000021c`00000393 ffff862f`61dc86b0
>   00000000`00000000 : nt!_report_gsfailure+0x25 ffffe70a`e08b4680
>   fffff803`1afa2c17 : 00000000`00000004 fffff803`1aefe23e
>   ffffe70a`e08b4900 ffffe70a`e08b47c0 : nt!_GSHandlerCheckCommon+0x5a
>   ffffe70a`e08b46b0 fffff803`1afcb1b2 : fffff803`1b311000
>   fffff803`1ae00000 0005e38c`00ab7000 00000000`0010001f :
>   nt!_GSHandlerCheck+0x13 ffffe70a`e08b46e0 fffff803`1aefa2d5 :
>   ffffe70a`e08b5648 00000000`00000000 ffffe70a`e08b4c50
>   00007fff`ffff0000 : nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0x12
>   ffffe70a`e08b4710 fffff803`1aefe86e : ffffe70a`e08b5648
>   ffffe70a`e08b5390 ffffe70a`e08b5648 00000000`00000018 :
>   nt!RtlDispatchException+0x4a5 ffffe70a`e08b4e60 fffff803`1afd431d :
>   00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000000
>   00000000`00000000 : nt!KiDispatchException+0x16e ffffe70a`e08b5510
>   fffff803`1afce8ab : 00000000`00000000 ffff9887`00000000
>   ffff9887`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0x11d
>   ffffe70a`e08b56f0 fffff803`1b500010 : fffff803`1b47fdc2
>   00000000`40003002 ffffe70a`e08b59c0 ffff9887`5381d8c0 :
>   nt!KiInvalidOpcodeFault+0x32b ffffe70a`e08b5888 ffff9887`513c74c0 :
>   00000000`00000001 ffff9887`3d0e40c0 ffffe70a`e08b5901
>   00000000`00000000 :
>   nt!PipChangeDeviceObjectFromRegistryProperties+0x6c ffffe70a`e08b5988
>   00000000`00000001 : ffff9887`3d0e40c0 ffffe70a`e08b5901
>   00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : 0xffff9887`513c74c0
>   ffffe70a`e08b5990 ffff9887`3d0e40c0 : ffffe70a`e08b5901
>   00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000088`f0cff950 : 0x1
>   ffffe70a`e08b5998 ffffe70a`e08b5901 : 00000000`00000000
>   00000000`00000001 00000088`f0cff950 00000000`00000000 :
>   0xffff9887`3d0e40c0 ffffe70a`e08b59a0 00000000`00000000 :
>   00000000`00000001 00000088`f0cff950 00000000`00000000
>   ffff9887`49b1e9f0 : 0xffffe70a`e08b5901
>
> THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  5623a1b98475ed6ab422ac153734b81ff4cf1dbe
>
> THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET: 
>   7ad2c9f635f506810a75d2f7d9c01177b7a094a4
>
> THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  bc100a5647b828107ac4e18055e00abcbe1ec406
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  nt!_report_gsfailure+25 fffff803`1b07c8a5 cc
>   int     3
>
> FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  cccccccc
>
> SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!_report_gsfailure+25
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: nt
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb
>
> BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  25
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xF7_MISSING_GSFRAME_nt!_report_gsfailure
>
> BUCKET_ID:  0xF7_MISSING_GSFRAME_nt!_report_gsfailure
>
> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xF7_MISSING_GSFRAME_nt!_report_gsfailure
>
> TARGET_TIME:  2020-04-03T22:02:33.000Z
>
> OSBUILD:  18362
>
> OSSERVICEPACK:  0
>
> SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0
>
> OS_REVISION: 0
>
> SUITE_MASK:  272
>
> PRODUCT_TYPE:  1
>
> OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64
>
> OSNAME:  Windows 10
>
> OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS
>
> OS_LOCALE:
>
> USER_LCID:  0
>
> OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date
>
> BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202
>
> BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release
>
> BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
>
> ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  2690
>
> ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM
>
> FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xf7_missing_gsframe_nt!_report_gsfailure
>
> FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {82d2c1b5-b0cb-60a5-9a5d-78c8c4284f84}
>
> ### Followup:     MachineOwner

Comment: "I'm getting this BSOD while playing CS GO" I would focus on that being the culprit.

Comment: Also see this to find the possible driver causing it>>>>>>https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/where-can-you-find-the-name-of-a-driver-causing-a-kernel-mode-crash